# IMetaDataDispenser::DefineScope() fails with E_NOTIMPL (0x80004001)

Tags: c++, c, winapi, windows-runtime, winmd

I'm trying to write .winmd metadata that represents a (COM) API. As I understand this functionality is provided via the [`IMetaDataDispenser`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/unmanaged-api/metadata/imetadatadispenser-interface) and related interfaces, that can be requested through the [`MetaDataGetDispenser()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/rometadata/nf-rometadata-metadatagetdispenser) API.

As a first test, I was trying to instantiate an `IMetaDataDispenser` interface and define an empty scope ([`IMetaDataDispenser::DefineScope()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/unmanaged-api/metadata/imetadatadispenser-definescope-method)) on it. After a bit of research, I managed to solve the former, but the latter is failing. Calling `DefineScope()` returns an `HRESULT` value of `E_NOTIMPL`:

```cpp
#include <objbase.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "Ole32.lib")
#include <rometadata.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "Rometadata.lib")
#include <cor.h>

int main()
{
    auto hr = ::CoInitialize(nullptr);

    IMetaDataDispenser* pDispenser = NULL;
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        hr = ::MetaDataGetDispenser(CLSID_CorMetaDataDispenser,
                                    IID_IMetaDataDispenser, (void**)&pDispenser);
    }

    IMetaDataEmit* pEmit = NULL;
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        hr = pDispenser->DefineScope(CLSID_CorMetaDataRuntime, 0,
                                     IID_IMetaDataEmit, (IUnknown**)&pEmit);
    }

    if (pEmit)
        pEmit->Release();
    if (pDispenser)
        pDispenser->Release();

    return hr;
}
```

What is the issue here and how do I resolve it?

Comment: if you under debugger step in to `pDispenser->DefineScope` you can view next implementation - `{ return E_NOTIMPL; }` https://i.imgur.com/GPWCmN4.png

Comment: cor.h is the old .NET Framework thing, you should be using RoMetadataApi.h nevertheless, only OpenScope and OpenScopeOnMemory seem to be implemented.

Comment: @SimonMourier I *am* using the RoMetadata API. That's where `MetaDataGetDispenser()` comes from. It isn't inherently different from .NET's. You could just as well `CoCreateInstance()` the COM object, but that takes a hard dependency on the .NET framework. And with .winmd files being ECMA-335 I don't understand why there should be any difference. Sadly, I still don't know how to write .winmd metadata (without re-implementing the file format).

Comment: AFAIK, midl is the only official tool to create winmd files. Microsoft own packages use midl to create winmd: https://github.com/microsoft/win32metadata/blob/main/sources/GeneratorSdk/MetadataTasks/CompileIdls.cs However midl comes with a file named `midlrtmd.dll` in `Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.22621.0\x64` that also exports `MetaDataGetDispenser` (LoadLibrary+GetProcAddress) and this one dispenser does support `DefineScope`. Not sure how far you can go from here.

Comment: @SimonMourier That looks promising (even if unsupported). I'll see where this gets me. Thanks!

Comment: @SimonMourier Completely unrelated, the following [MagNumDB query](https://www.magnumdb.com/search?q=IID_IUnknown) returns two different values for `IID_IUnknown`. Do you know what's up with that?

Comment: @IInspectable - usually it's because there are different values for different #if preproc conditions (check "Conditions" checkbox). Here it's just another value from a strange file (check "File path" checkbox), `%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.22621.0\km\punknown.h` (from WDK). An old typo bug maybe...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What is the issue [...]?

In a nutshell: Part of the `IMetaDataDispenser` interface is intended for internal use only, with the documentation failing to make that apparent.

It appears that the consumer-facing API surface is public. It exposes services to query the database if you already have a .winmd file. The part of the API concerned with producing a .winmd file, on the other hand, isn't accessible through the `CLSID_CorMetaDataDispenser` implementation that ships with the system. The only "documentation" is the respective interfaces returning `E_NOTIMPL` for those private parts.

> [H]ow do I resolve it?

There isn't, to my knowledge, a public API that can be used to produce a .winmd file. The only officially supported avenue to creating a .winmd file is the [midlrt.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/midl/midlrt-and-windows-runtime-components) compiler. This works when you have a WinRT IDL (aka [MIDL v3](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/midl-3/)) source. Lacking that the only other options are:

- Work through [ECMA-335](https://ecma-international.org/publications-and-standards/standards/ecma-335/) (Partition II) and implement it
- Go undocumented and use the `CLSID_CorMetaDataDispenser` implementation that ships with the SDK

The second option was discovered by Simon in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77993960/imetadatadispenserdefinescope-fails-with-e-notimpl-0x80004001#comment137508523_77993960). The SDK ships with a binary (*midlrtmd.dll*) that exports, among others, the function `MetaDataGetDispenser()`. Making sure that its signature [matches](https://dogbolt.org/?id=42bbad61-f85a-464e-a32c-72261b846e28#Hex-Rays=2062) that of the public [`MetaDataGetDispenser()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/rometadata/nf-rometadata-metadatagetdispenser) API I went ahead and took it for a spin.

The following implementation compiles as x64 as long as the referenced SDK is available on the system:

```cpp
#include <objbase.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "Ole32.lib")
#include <rometadata.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "Rometadata.lib")
#include <cor.h>

#include <Windows.h>

typedef HRESULT(STDAPICALLTYPE* fn_ptr)(REFCLSID, REFIID, LPVOID*);

int main()
{
    auto hr = ::CoInitialize(nullptr);

    auto const module = ::LoadLibraryW(LR"(C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.22621.0\x64\midlrtmd.dll)");
    if (!module)
        hr = E_FAIL;

    fn_ptr MyMetaDataGetDispenser = nullptr;
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        MyMetaDataGetDispenser = reinterpret_cast<fn_ptr>(::GetProcAddress(module, "MetaDataGetDispenser"));
        if (!MyMetaDataGetDispenser)
            hr = E_FAIL;
    }

    IMetaDataDispenser* pDispenser = NULL;
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        hr = MyMetaDataGetDispenser(CLSID_CorMetaDataDispenser,
                                    IID_IMetaDataDispenser, (void**)&pDispenser);
    }

    IMetaDataEmit* pEmit = NULL;
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        hr = pDispenser->DefineScope(CLSID_CorMetaDataRuntime, 0,
                                     IID_IMetaDataEmit, (IUnknown**)&pEmit);
    }

    if (pEmit)
        pEmit->Release();
    if (pDispenser)
        pDispenser->Release();

    return hr;
}
```

This code successfully returns an `IMetaDataEmit` interface that appears to be fully functional. [`Save()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/unmanaged-api/metadata/imetadataemit-save-method)-ing it to a file shows a `BSJB` blob, that subsequently needs to be embedded into a PE image.

It's not a complete .winmd file yet, but a step forward.

Comment: I came across this project (from a Microsoft dev working on dotnet) that might by of interest https://github.com/AaronRobinsonMSFT/DNMD

Comment: @SimonMourier That looks like a rewrite of the consumer API, that part I'm not interested in. I'm implementing a *producer*. Meanwhile, I've successfully hijacked *midlrtmd.dll*, implemented a PE image writer, and produced a .winmd that's accepted by [ILSpy](https://github.com/icsharpcode/ILSpy), [cppwinrt](https://github.com/microsoft/xlang), and [windows-bindgen](https://crates.io/crates/windows-bindgen), so things are looking good. Thanks for the reference nonetheless!